# NASM syntax in GDB

Tags: assembly, gdb, nasm

I can assign Intel syntax to GDB, but there are differentes between NASM and MASM as:

```
NASM: mov eax,[variable]
MASM: mov eax,variable
```

How can I assign NASM syntax to GDB?

Comment: Short answer: you can't.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot.  GDB supports only AT&T and Intel.  NASM uses a very similar (but slightly different) macro assembler format.